# How to get word inside xml tag name php?

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml file https://pastebin.com/2PFthem2

I want to get the "Classroom" property of all lectures to print it in an array Html

example Classroom="B3" i want the B3

Code so far

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($xml1);
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$events = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Event');
foreach ($events as $event){
$lessonTitles = $event->getElementsByTagName('Title');
$Lectures = $event->getElementsByTagName( "Lecture" );
$Lecture = array();
$Day = array();
$Time = array();
echo 'LessonTitle: '.$lessonTitles->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getAttribute()` method,

```php
$lectures = $event->getElementsByTagName( "Lecture" );

$classRoomArray = [];

foreach($lectures as $lecture) {
   // getting Classroom attribute of each leature element
   $classRoom = $lecture->getAttribute('Classroom');

   //push to classroom array
   array_push($classRoomArray, $classRoom);

}


echo $classRoomArray; // will print all classroom attribute of all lecture element
```

Comment: that is great!Furthermore inside lecture i can get Day and Time my using getElementsByTagName() with the tag Day and Time?